# Blazor Component in Razor Class Library (CSS Isolation)

Tags: css, blazor, blazor-webassembly, razor-class-library

I have created a component:

**MyComponent.razor**

and added a css file:

**MyComponent.razor.css**

The css file nested under the component file in Visual Studio, so I know there are no spelling mistakes.
This is in a Razor class library.

I was getting odd behaviour which I tracked down to a class-name clash with a bootstrap class, which is also loaded in my Index.cshtml file.

I renamed my class names in my component to avoid the clash and everything worked as I expected.

But, my understanding was using this naming convention for css file would mean that all class names in HTML and class names in CSS file would get this random b-?????????? suffix/attribute to avoid such name clashes.

Have I misunderstood CSS Isolation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS isolation only applies to .razor pages so selectors will still find the subcomponents without `::deep` from other .css files

Answer (score 2):

The docs say that

> For each styled component, an HTML attribute is appended with the format `b-<10-character-string>`.

You can inspect the `{Project Name}.styles.css` file in your browser to see the generated css, like

```
h1[b-3xxtam6d07] {
    color: brown;
}
```

Be sure to include `::deep` so the CSS reaches child components of MyComponent.

Here is the source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#css-isolation-bundling